# Using variables in sed - not sure if it is working

Tags: bash, sed

I am creating a variable, and a part of how it is created involved `sed -n`. The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure if it is working.

`y=$(ls -Ap | grep "/$" | sed -n "$ip")` is the first line and creates y.

But when I run

`echo $y` I simply get no output and a blank space. So I'm not sure if the sed is working or not, and if not how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to bracket your variable i.e `sed -n "${i}p"`

Comment: That's great thanks, works perfectly. Out of interest does the variable part always need to be bracketed?

Comment: only if it is followed by a character,number or underscore, but it is good practice to always bracket it as it makes it clearer what the variable is called and also has no ill effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As User 123 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613492/using-variables-in-sed-not-sure-if-it-is-working#comment56972286_34613492), the problem is that bash tries to expand `$ip` instead of `$i`. You can use curly braces around the variable name to avoid that, like this `${i}`.

However, I don't suggest to use the pipe solution since:

- [Parsing the output of ls is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- You are using one tool too much, either `grep` or `sed` would be enough.

I suggest to use `find`: It can be done with a single invocation of `find`:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*${i}*"
```

Make sure that `${i}` is set and not empty! Otherwise `-name` would expand to `-name "**"` which would match anything. You can do that using [*parameter substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) syntax:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*${i:-nonexistent}*"
```

Make sure that `nonexistent` does not exist! ;)

Comment: Excellent suggestion to use `find`. Also, if `${i}` is actually a regex (as might be suggested by the OP's usage), find's `-regex` or `-iregex` option might be more appropriate than `-name`. Also, you can avoid the "anything" match (which you warn about) by using something like `"*${i:-nonexistent}*"`

Comment: @ghoti Good points! Especially `"*${i:-nonexistent}*"` should be used. Let me add that. Thanks!

Comment: You can also complain with `${i:?Error message}`; this even stops a script.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I guess in this case the variable `v` (the result from command substitution) should simply be empty in that case rather than stopping the whole script. However, if so desired `${i:?Error message}` is also pretty nice to use.